# Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

I am making an httr::GET request and the following is being returned.

```
Response [https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX/XX/XXXXXXX/icehockey_nhl/scores? 
apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&daysFrom=1&dateFormat=iso]
Date: 2023-02-20 05:59
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Size: 3.48 kB
[{"id":"6b40a20e8fa1b2ca0101286a21f0b18b","sport_key":"icehockey_nhl","sport_title"
```

I then run jsonlite::fromJson and get the following error

```
Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
```

While I have seen a few workarounds I haven't seen an answer as to why the error occurs.  As you can can see the response is JSON.  I would rather not have to introduce additional steps if the data is in fact JSON.  Ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `content(x, "parsed")`. Error occurs because a response object is a list that contains more than just the content (stored as a raw vector) so you can't pass it to `fromJSON()` directly.

Comment: Thanks Ritchie.  What is odd is that it works for some requests but doesn't work for others, and from the same API.  I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use the package RJSONIO as below?

```
library(RJSONIO)
url='http://ip.jsontest.com/'
data <- fromJSON(url)
```

Comment: Thanks SBMVNO.  This works.  But as I commented above, what is odd is that the request works for some API requests and not others, from the same provider.  I will give this a try.

Comment: Without knowing your API, it is impossible to tell why it works in one way but not another way.